# Ошибка в дискорд боте на node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, бот, discord

Пишу бота на node.js для выдачи ролей через нажатие на реакцию. Столкнулся с тем, что после нажатия на реакцию созданного сообщения, выходит данная ошибка. Как можно пофиксить ее?  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код бота:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new discord.Client();

client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("Bot started");
});

client.on('raw', event => {
        const eventName = event.t;
        if(eventName === 'MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD')
        {
            if(event.d.message_id === '703668458533158962')
            {
                var reactionChannel = client.channels.get(event.d.channel_id);
                if(reactionChannel.messages.has(event.d.message_id))
                    return;
                else {
                    reactionChannel.fetchMessage(event.d.message_id)
                    .then(msg => {
                        console.log(event.d)
                        var msgReaction = event.d.emoji.name;
                        var user = client.users.get(event.d.user_id);
                        client.emit('messageReactionAdd', msgReaction, user);
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err));
                }
            }
        }       
});

    client.on('messageReactionAdd', (messageReaction, user) => {
        console.log(messageReaction)

        var roleName = messageReaction;
        console.log(roleName);
        var role = messageReaction.message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name.toLowerCase() === roleName.toLowerCase());

        console.log(messageReaction)
        console.log(role)
        if(role)
        {
            var member = messageReaction.message.guild.members.find(member => member.id === user.id);
            if(mmeber)
            {
            member.addRole(role,id);
            console.log("Succes");
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: Тут два варианта: либо сделать так, чтобы у объекта `messageReaction` было поле `message`, либо не пытаться брать поле `guild`, если поля `message` нет.

Comment: @Yaant, а не подскажите, что именно добавить/убрать? Я просто не особо понимаю пока в написании ботов, да и в доке как-то не особо для меня понятно описано.

Comment: Ну, если Вы вручную эмитите событие (не берусь судить о целесообразности этого), то надо позаботиться о том, чтобы передаваемые параметры имели нужную структуру. В частности, `msgReaction` должен иметь тип [`MessageReaction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction)

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался сам :) Просто код переписал немного по другому.